# Cómo pasar una propiedad entre comillas en vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

mi problema con vue.js y BootstrapVue es el siguiente:

Tengo una imagen que quiero cargar desde una dirección q guardo en una propiedad y quiero mostrarla en el atributo src,pero al intentar esto:

```
<b-img :src=“require(‘image’)”></b-img>

<script>
export default{
name: ‘X’,
data(){
   return{
   image:’@/assets/photo.png’
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

No me carga las comillas simples dentro del require y no reconoce el path donde está la imagen.
He intentado escapar las comillas simples, pero no he encontrado la solución a mi problema.
Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para importar la imagen utilizando el path en la propiedad 'image' del estado del componente debes utilizar la siguiente sintaxis:

```
<b-img :src="require(`${image}`)"></b-img>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'X',
  data() {
    return {
      image: '@/assets/photo.png'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Otra alternativa igualmente válida, sería:

```
<b-img :src="image"></b-img>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'X',
  data() {
    return {
      image: require('@/assets/photo.png')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Te comparto un ejemplo funcional de ambas opciones en CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-tree-ol2mn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark

Comment: He intentado hacer eso pero no me funciona. Lanza una advertencia: “Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression”

Comment: @AlejandroErnestoMontanoCord Es cierto, he corregido mi respuesta, anexo una liga con un ejemplo funcional de las alternativas que propongo

Comment: Gracias por tu solución, me funciono perfectamente. No se me había ocurrido la segunda alternativa que parece sencilla.